# MissingMethod Exception C# How to trace

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, missingmethodexception

i have a Missing Method Exception in my program stated that there is a method missing in my code, the problem is i have the method reside in my code, i have tried to clean, rebuild delete and add the dll file, same things occur, i also try to remap my project from team foundation server and the problems remain, below is  "Missing Method" from Missing Method Exception [ScreenShot of Exception Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC0mK.png):

```
    public static SQLiteDataStore MyDataStore
    {
        get
        {
            if (DatabaseUsed == DatabaseType.Loaded)
            {
                if (_isIntializedNew)
                    return _myLoadedDataInstance;
                else
                {
                    _myLoadedDataInstance = new SQLiteDataStore(LoadedDatabaseFullPath);
                    _myLoadedDataInstance.CreateOrUpdateStore();
                    _myLoadedDataInstance.ConnectionBehavior = ConnectionBehavior.Persistent;
                    _myLoadedDataInstance.RecoveryEnabled = false;
                    _isIntializedNew = true;
                    GetAllEntities();
                    return _myLoadedDataInstance;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_isIntialized)
                    return _myCurrentDataInstance;
                else
                {
                    _myCurrentDataInstance = new SQLiteDataStore(CurrentDatabaseFullPath);
                    _myCurrentDataInstance.CreateOrUpdateStore();
                    _myCurrentDataInstance.ConnectionBehavior = ConnectionBehavior.Persistent;
                    _myCurrentDataInstance.RecoveryEnabled = false;
                    _isIntialized = true;
                    GetAllEntities();
                    return _myCurrentDataInstance;
                }
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (DatabaseUsed == DatabaseType.Loaded)
            {
                _myLoadedDataInstance = value; _isIntializedNew = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _myCurrentDataInstance = value; _isIntialized = false;
            }
        }


    }
```

Anyone have any idea how to trace the root cause of these or solution to solve this issues?

Comment: Is it possible that the DLL has changed slightly in the definition of that function, perhaps the arguments or the return type has been altered?  You haven't really given us much information to work on.  Has this project ever been built successfully in the past?

Comment: hi there, yes the project run smooth in the past and also present in my colleague machine, for your information, the method name have been altered once, previously this method is named myCurrentDataStore, i have tried to delete and re add all the dll and rebuild project, the problem remains.

Comment: Has the namespace changed? Or has the type of the returned value changed?

Comment: no, only the definition of the function changed

Comment: In the screenshot, it looks like it is attempting to use the method with the updated name, so it should know it has changed. Can you access it through a different program / project without any errors? Can you verify that the referenced assembly is in fact the one with the updated method, and not a previous one (check the file path and the creation/modified dates)?

Comment: my colleague can access it, i have verified that the assembly is the updated method,is there any other causes? Why is the exception being thrown?

Comment: From what you have posted, I can't figure out what the cause of the problem is. I found an MSDN article that mentions several causes to `MissingMethodException` - [Click here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2004/02/13/debugging-a-missingmethodexception-missingfieldexception-typeloadexception.aspx) to read the article.

Comment: hi Lars, i found your post on google when i looking for solution online, thanks for the article, will keep you updated.

Comment: Hi @LarsKristensen, just want to ask, if there is log in the fusion log, means there is failure occur when loading dlls?

Comment: @SoonEe I'm afraid I don't know. My gut tells me that the DLL is loaded correctly, and that this issue may have something to do with versioning - either the version of the DLL doesn't match the expected version, or maybe the Target Framework version has changed or doesn't match with the code that uses the DLL.

Comment: @LarsKristensen you were right, the dll loaded correctly, right now i am still trying to trace the root cause, do you have any suggestion?